# javascript function to validate a number from php?

Tags: php, javascript

how to make a javascript function to validate a number whether its in between the minimum and maximum numbers in php?

```
$dbosminsalary
$dbosmaxsalary
$dblastdate

<form action='workaction.php' method='post'>

<input type='number' id='amntpreferred' name='amntpreferred' class='required input_field' placeholder='Enter bid value' oninput='numberBetween();' required/> 

<script>

 function numberBetween(amntpreferred, $dbosmaxsalary, $dbosminsalary) 
 {
    if(amntpreferred <= $dbosminsalary) 
          return false;
    else if(amntpreferred >= $dbosmaxsalary)  
          return false;
    else
          return true;
 }
 if (numberBetween(amntpreferred,$dbosmaxsalary,$dbosminsalary)) 
 {
    echo 'The value is in the range!';
 } 
 else 
 {
    echo 'The value is outside the range!';
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `whether its in between the minimum and maximum numbers in php?` Means

Comment: echo 'string'; is erroneous in Javascript.  Alternatives are console.log('string'); or setting DOM page elements to a value.

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this example here

```
<?php

$min = 1;
$max = 10;

?>

<script>
    function inRange(x) {

        if((x >= <?php echo $min; ?>) && (x <= <?php echo $max; ?>))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    if(inRange(77))
        alert("it's ok");
    else
        alert("it's not ok");

</script>
```

now please have a close look on it and try to implement it on your code, the important thing is that you understand it

Comment: Here is how this page works.  When php creates a web page, it can embed javascript scripts or any other text into the web page, but it doesn't run any of the Javascript on the server, it can only get it ready for the browser. In this case the <?php echo inserts the minimum and maximum values into a script to be run on the browser.  The web page is then sent over the internet as a bunch of text, or compressed text, to the user's browser.  When the user's browser runs the script in the page, it runs in the browser's interpreter, which can run javascript (but knows nothing about PHP).